# Wrong numbering of tables in appendix

Tags: tables, longtable

I have an appendix with 26 tables. Strangely, table 22 which should be positioned after table 21 gets automatically positioned after table 2 (cf. picture). [image]

This happens for the two tables that I use the environment "longtable" for.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage{tabulary}
    \usepackage[maxfloats=30,morefloats=12]{morefloats}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{float,lscape}
    \usepackage{longtable}
   \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{bigstrut}

    \begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{European gymnastics associations 1899}
  \tiny
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LRRR}
    \hlinewd{1.25pt}
......
 \hlinewd{1.25pt}
    \end{tabulary}%
    \vspace{5pt}
    \captionsetup{font={scriptsize}}
    \caption*{Source: Eidgenössischer Turnverein (1899), own illustration}
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

    \begingroup
    \centering
    \tiny
    \begin{longtable}[htbp]{*{5}1}
      \caption{Zurich gymnastics organization in 1907}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{Association} & Paying members & Non-paying members & Total & Active members \bigstrut\\
        \hline
......
\hline
        Total & 10840 & 2422  & 13262 & 2460 \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        \end{longtable}%
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \endgroup%

\begingroup
\centering
\tiny%
\begin{longtable}[h!]{*{7}l}
  \caption{Account of the Zurich gymnastics organization 1911}   
 \tabularnewline
...
 \hline
    Total &       &       & 13'359 & 2'812 & 16'171 & 2'767 \bigstrut\\
%    \hlinewd{1.25pt}
\end{longtable}
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\endgroup

    \end{document}
```

Does it maybe have something to do with the \begingroup and \endgroup commands? How can I ensure that the two tables with the longtable environment are positioned at the right place?

Comment: `table` environments float, `longtable` doesn't.

Comment: How can I make longtable float?

Comment: `\begin{longtable}[htbp]` is an error `longtable` only takes `[c]`, `[l]` or `[r]` options (and as you want centering you do not need an option at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not (really) make `longtable` float, (nor does `\centering` have any effect on `lingtable`. The simplest fix is to put `\clearpage` before the `longtable` which will flush out any pending floats at a forced page break and stop them floating past `longtable`.

(The `longtable` documentation does warn that this might happen)